# Detect bad acceleration deceleration of car

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I am working on aggressive driving behavior android application.
This will be implemented via supervised learning, wrong actions will be recognized and added while driving the car. 
To check aggressive turns i am using centripetal force. When exceeds set force, wrong action will be detected.
I want to check if the acceleration or deceleration of car is safe or not?
Not using a single maximum value but something more reliable like a pattern or something.

Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that somebody should use a mobile phone app while driving. That doesn't sound very safe.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Not like that....
This application when once learns driving behavior, with help of front seater **not driver**..  
App will then generate report of the driving behavior when put in the car stand.

Comment: Where do you get your baseline from? Also, what is your actual question? You seem to be saying, "Here is my product idea, now how can I do this?" -- that's too broad a question for this site, and arguably not even computer *science*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.  The question "what level of acceleration is safe?" is not a question about computer science; it is a question about cars and automotive safety.  As a result, this question does not appear to be suitable for this site.